# MVVM create textbox and set binding on viewmodel

Tags: mvvm, binding, textbox, viewmodel, dynamically-generated

I have an empty stackpanel on View and I need to add textboxes on ViewModel. Same time I need to set binding to Text property for this textboxes.

VIEW :

```
    <StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myBtCollection}"></ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

VIEWMODEL :

```
        public decimal textExample { get; set; }
        public decimal textExample2 { get; set; }
        public decimal textExample3 { get; set; }


        public ObservableCollection<TextBox> myTxCollection { get; set; }

public ExampleViewModel()
{
            myTxCollection = new ObservableCollection<TextBox>();

            TextBox txt1 = new TextBox { Text = textExample.ToString() }; 
            TextBox txt2 = new TextBox { Text = textExample2.ToString() };
            TextBox txt3 = new TextBox { Text = textExample3.ToString() };

           myTxCollection.Add(txt1);
           myTxCollection.Add(txt2);
           myTxCollection.Add(txt3);
}

public void ExampleCommand()
{
textExample = 123;
textExample2 = 456;
textExample3 = 789; 
}
```

By this codes, I can create the textboxes. But some methods(ExampleCommands) in ViewModel, I change the values textExample properties. 
Summary code run first time; textboxes created successfully and text values are 0. And then I trigged the ExampleCommand, properties are changed but View didnt show this changes. Textboxes are showing still 0. How must be set the binding for this?
Thanks

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the containing class...

Comment: This is anything but MVVM. Your view model should not be creating any UI elements, rather than data that the UI can bind to. I suggest you read more about the basics of MVVM.